# SQL query to make distinct lines with case being used

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Here is what my data looks like on the table I am querying

Table 1

```
ITEM     SEQUENCE     CODE
Item1       1            A 
Item1       2            B
Item2       1            B
Item2       2            C
Item2       3            D
```

My current Query looks like

```
  Select Distinct Table1.ITEM, 
  case when Table1.SEQUENCE = '1' Then Table2.DSC end As FirstDSC,
  Case When Table1.SEQUENCE = '2' then Table2.DSC End As SecondDSC,
  Case When Table1.SEQUENCE = '3' Then Table2.DSC End As ThirdDSC
    From Table1
    Join Table2 on Table2.Code = Table1.Code
    Where Table1.Item In (Subquery here to find distinct values that Item can be)
```

It currently returns the data looking like

```
ITEM  FIRSTDSC SECONDDSC THIRDDSC
Item1   DSC-A     NULL      NULL
Item1   NULL     DSC-B      NULL
```

I was wondering how to make the data return looking like

```
ITEM FIRSTDSC  SECONDDSC  THIRDDSC
Item1  DSC-A      DSC-B       NULL
Item2  DSC-B      DSC-C       DSC-D
```

Is there a good way to do this or am I going in the completely wrong direction with my query currently?

Comment: You can do this with a PIVOT or CROSSTAB. Both have hundreds of answers around here and everywhere else on the web. Also, you should only tag relevant DBMS. Are you using both mysql AND sql server?

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry about the tags just hit both of the recommend ones without paying too much attention. Is there a way to remove the mysql one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `group by` and conditional aggregation, not `distinct`:

```
Select Table1.ITEM, 
       max(case when Table1.SEQUENCE = '1' Then Table2.DSC end) As FirstDSC,
       max(Case When Table1.SEQUENCE = '2' then Table2.DSC End) As SecondDSC,
       max(Case When Table1.SEQUENCE = '3' Then Table2.DSC End) As ThirdDSC
From Table1 Join
     Table2
     on Table2.Code = Table1.Code
Where Table1.Item In (Subquery here to find distinct values that Item can be)
group by table1.ITEM;
```

Comment: Yep this is how I would do it. This technique is also known as a cross tab.

Comment: Thank you for the help! This worked perfectly. I also didn't know what a Crosstab or pivot was prior to asking this question, for thank you for enlightening me to two methods on how to complete this task @SeanLange